# Unexpected token error exporting enums using yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a project in typescript, with the structure like this:

```
root/
  packges/
    client/ <-- Built with CRA
    server/
    domain/
      src/models
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
      webpack.config.js
```

Importing a model such as `@project/domain/src/models/some-model.ts` inside the client project seems to work fine (or at least the linter doesn't complain about it). However, when I run the app, I get this error:

```
../domain/src/models/some-model.ts 12:7
[1] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:7)
[1] File was processed with these loaders:
[1]  * ../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
[1] You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
[1] > export enum SomeEnum {
[1] |   VALUE1,
[1] |   VALUE2
```

I'm guessing that this is because the domain 'app' itself isn't being run, just referenced, so its webpack config is ignored. But if that's the case then how can I get this to properly work?

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/' }]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src"]
```

Some other relevant questions:

1. I'm not planning to put shared code aside from models in `domain`, so is it necessary for it to have a src folder? Can I somehow get it as bare-bones as possible, or does it have to be a full-on runnable sub-project?
2. Is it necessary to use node references in package.json when using yarn workspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deciding not to program at 5am, I used a different search term and was finally able to google the answer. Basically, this error is due to CRA not allowing code outside the src directory. So the fix is either ejecting, using `react-app-rewired`, or using `craco` which is what I went with. To answer my own misc questions:

1. I moved out the `models` folder into the root of the `domain` directory/package. I don't know if this is good practice per say but looking at the import path without `src` makes me feel better.
2. Nope

Comment: What does CRA mean?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Create-react-app